# Ajustar div al tamaño de una celda

Tags: css

Estoy intentando que los divs `.escalaResponse`, quede a la misma anchura de la celda, pero que no la haga más alta, intenté con `position: relative` pero eso hace el div del 100% del body creo y se sale a lo ancho pero ya no modifica la atura, como puedo combinar las posiciones, para que no se salga del ancho y tampoco se haga más grande la celda

```js
$(function(){
  var p = $('.panel');
  $(p).find('table').DataTable();
});
```

```css
    th, td{
      text-align: center;
    }

    .toggler{
      cursor: pointer;
      font-size: 1.5rem;
    }

    .finder{
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 120px;
    max-height: 120px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
    position: absolute;
    /*position: relative;*/
    border-radius: 3px;
    }

    .smallest{
      font-size: 1px;
      color: #fff;
      margin: 0 !important;
      padding: 0 !important;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <style media="screen">

  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel">
          <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Usuario</th>
                <th>Gerente</th>
                <th>Escalamiento</th>
                <th>Acción</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr data-id="1">
                <td>foo</td>
                <td>bar</td>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm escalaSearch" value="poo">
                  <div class="escalaResponse finder"></div>
                  <span class="smallest">poo</span>

                </td>
                <td>
                  <i style="color:green;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle toggler"></i>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Me gustaría resolverlo por CSS, sin tener que meterle mano al JS.

Comment: No me queda claro: ¿quieres el div `.escalaResponse.` con la anchura de la celda?

Comment: Si, eso necesito, que quede del ancho de la celda, pero que tampoco haga más alta la celda, se me ocurrió position:fixed, pero no quiero que ande flotando por muchos lados, además que tendré varias con el mismo estilo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se me ocurre lo siguiente:

El padre (celda) tendrá `position:relative` (que no afecta a como se ve, pero afecta a los hijos).

El hijo tendrá `position:absolute` que lo relaciona con el primer ascendiente que **no** tenga `position:static`.

Luego le añades un `margin-left: -10px`  para compensar el margen del padre y ahí lo tienes, centrado y del mismo ancho, pero sin afectar al tamaño del padre:

```js
$(function(){
  var p = $('.panel');
  $(p).find('table').DataTable();
});
```

```css
th, td{
  text-align: center;
  
  position:relative
}
.toggler{
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.finder{
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 120px;
max-height: 120px;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
background-color: #ffffff;
border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
position: absolute;

border-radius: 3px;
}

.smallest{
  font-size: 1px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.escalaResponse {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <style media="screen">

  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel">
          <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Usuario</th>
                <th>Gerente</th>
                <th>Escalamiento</th>
                <th>Acción</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr data-id="1">
                <td>foo</td>
                <td>bar</td>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm escalaSearch" value="poo">
                  <div class="escalaResponse finder"></div>
                  <span class="smallest">poo</span>

                </td>
                <td>
                  <i style="color:green;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle toggler"></i>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Gracias sensei, me sirvió.

Answer (score 1):

Ahí lo tienes, lo he hecho con `css`, he cambiado el `min-height` y `min-width`

```js
$(function(){
  var p = $('.panel');
  $(p).find('table').DataTable();
});
```

```css
th, td{
      text-align: center;
    }

    .toggler{
      cursor: pointer;
      font-size: 1.5rem;
    }

    .finder{
    min-width: 199px;
    min-height: 25px;
    max-height: 120px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
    position: absolute;
    /*position: relative;*/
    border-radius: 3px;
    }

    .smallest{
      font-size: 1px;
      color: #fff;
      margin: 0 !important;
      padding: 0 !important;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <style media="screen">

  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel">
          <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Usuario</th>
                <th>Gerente</th>
                <th>Escalamiento</th>
                <th>Acción</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr data-id="1">
                <td>foo</td>
                <td>bar</td>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm escalaSearch" value="poo">
                  <div class="escalaResponse finder"></div>
                  <span class="smallest">poo</span>

                </td>
                <td>
                  <i style="color:green;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle toggler"></i>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ya modifiqué mi pregunta, creo que me confundí con un selector, agradezco tu respuesta pero no es lo que necesito